# Surprising behavior of re-assigning a variable for every row in a select

Tags: sql-server

This is the simplest example with which I could reproduce the issue. As such it looks a little bit contrived, but bear with me.

```
declare @t table(number int)
insert into @t values (1), (2)

declare @sum bigint = 0

select @sum = @sum + number
    from (select top 2 number from @t order by number) subquery
    order by number desc

select @sum
```

[Here's the query on the data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/611308).

I would expect this to return 3, the sum of the values in the table `@t`. Instead, however, it returns 1.

Doing any of the following will cause the query to correctly return 3:

- make `@t.number` and `@sum` have the same type (by making `@sum` an `int` or `@t.number` a `bigint`).
- removing the outer `order by`
- removing the inner `order by`
- making both `order by`s sort in the same direction by adding `desc` to the inner one or removing it from the outer one
- removing the subquery (i.e. just selecting `from @t`)

None of these things strike me as something that should change the behavior of this query.

Swapping the sort orders (descending in the subquery, ascending on the outside) will make the query return 2 instead of 1.

A similar thing happens with strings instead of numbers, so this isn't constrained to `int` and `bigint`.

This happens both with SQL Server 2014 and 2016, or to be precise

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 10586: )
```

and

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-CU1) (KB3164674) - 13.0.2149.0 (X64)
Jul 11 2016 22:05:22
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )
```

(the latter being the data explorer).

What's going on?

Comment: The reliable way to assign the sum would be `SELECT @sum = SUM(number) FROM ...`. Performing an assignment in a `SELECT` when multiple rows are involved is asking for trouble -- you're essentially asking the optimizer to screw you over if it finds some really clever way of evaluating the query. I've heard people say this can't work, shouldn't work, will work under special circumstances or even that it's *guaranteed* to work under certain circumstances, but reliable sources are scarce. This may or may not be an optimizer bug, but considering a rewrite should be your first avenue of attack.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm just using the sum as a simple example. As I said, it's a little contrived.

Comment: I realize that, but the general advice stands. Finding a way to rewrite the row by row assignment to something set-based is your best bet (though doing this without losing performance or (horror) introducing cursors might be the tricky bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be that you are/were relying on undocumented behaviour which changed in Sql Server 2012.

Per the documentation:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx

> SELECT @local_variable is typically used to return a single value into the variable. However, when expression is the name of a column, it can return multiple values. If the SELECT statement returns more than one value, the variable is assigned the last value that is returned.

It is not documented what happens if the destination variable (to be assigned to) is part of the source expression. It seems this behaviour has changed. In earlier versions the variable would be assigned once for each row, but that doesn't seem to occur any more.

This is most visible for a lot of functions where the "group concat" trick ceased to work:

```
SELECT @sentence = @sentence + ' ' + word from  SENTENCE_WORDS order by position
```

These have generally to be replaced by the xml concat trick.

```
set @sentence = (
    select word as "text()", ' ' as "text()" 
    from SENTENCE_WORDS 
    order by position 
    for xml path(''), root('root'), type
).value('(/root)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

Comment: Your example works fine though: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/611317 (as would the corresponding version of my sum -- it's only the combination of type conversion, subquery, and two `order by`s that break it).

Comment: Indeed. But since it's not documented behaviour, you can't rely on it. It could change with a service pack, or an index change, or just a change of query plan... You don't know what may cause it to stop working.

Comment: ... neither do I know what may cause it to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second ORDER BY (I.e. "order by number desc").

You are using an undocumented feature of T-SQL (I believe it's called ROW concatenation?) which is not guaranteed to work in future versions of SQL.  It's a little hacky, but very useful none-the-less!  As you've discovered, it breaks when you use the ORDER BY clause.  This is a known issue of using Row concatenation.